# Controlling 2 motors from the same controller

Tags: motor

[image]12 V DC system. A large windlass motor(A) is controlled from distance with solenoids. The motor has 3 terminals, 1 is common ground (negative), 2 and 3 are positive. When UP button is pressed the motor turns one way and when pressed DOWN the motor turns the other way.

1. I assume that if I use a multimeter to read the voltage on the terminals I should read when pressing UP 12 V between e.g. 1 and 2 and 0 V between 1 and 3, when pressing DOWN 0 V between 1 and 2 and 12 V between 1 and 3. Correct?
2. Ι have another motor (B) that I want to control too, taking power from those same terminals. The B motor has also 3 cables. Cable 1 is negative, cable 2 connected to positive makes the motor turn ,cable 3 when connected to positive makes motor turn to «park» position.
   My plan is to connect those two motors with the same controller so when I press UP, A motor turns and motor B goes PARK and when DOWN both motor ps turn together.
   [image]

Comment: 1. why are you assuming and not measuring? ... `Correct ?` that cannot be answered without any information

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic of what you have.

Comment: No, these assumptions are not justified. Find out what the terminals are for. For example one could be armature windings and one could be field windings and the direction could be reversed by applying a negative voltage.

Comment: So I get 12v between BLUE and ANY red wire even when I press UP or DOWN